# Silly Question about a validation case in Java and temporary variables

Tags: java, hibernate

How does one set a temporary variable of date before it is updated? I would like to compare my initial date before it is updated.

Update: More code

```
 * @hibernate.class table="t3sstations"
 * @hibernate.join name="rgnjoin" table="stnregions" optional="true"
 * @hibernate.join-key column="idstn"
 */
public class Station extends BaseSiteChildCFKObject implements Convertible, Comparable<Station> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2056063261398467275L;
    protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private Project stationProject;
    private Date project_startdate;
    private Date date_initial;
```

Table it grabs from SQL using hibernate. It grabs the project's date from the column project_startdate. I want to compare the date that it is initially with the new/updated date. It updates the same value throughout the class.

```
    /**
     * @return
     * @hibernate.many-to-one column="idproject" not-null="false"
     * class="org.unavco.pbo.mdm.model.Project"
     */
    @Required
    public Project getStationProject() {
        return stationProject;
    }

    public void setStationProject(Project stationProject) {
        this.stationProject = stationProject;
    }


    /**
     * @return
     * @hibernate.property column="project_startdate"
     */

    public Date getProject_startdate() {
        return project_startdate;
    }


    public void setProject_startdate(Date project_startdate) {
            this.project_startdate = project_startdate;
    }
```

```
@AssertTrue
    private boolean validateProjectDate() {

        project_initialdate = new Date(project_startdate);

        if (project_startdate.before(this.project_initialdate)){
            return false;
        }

        if (project_startdate.before(this.stationProject.getStart_date()))  {

            return false;
        }

        if (this.stationProject.getEnd_date() != null) {
            if (this.project_startdate.after(this.stationProject.getEnd_date())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You declare it and you assign something to it.  Or you declare it with an initializer.

Comment: Like this? 
```
private Date project_initialdate; 
And in the function: project_initialdate = getProject_startdate;
 public Date getProject_initialdate() {
  return project_initialdate;
 }


 public void setProject_initialdate(Date project_initialdate) {
  this.project_initialdate = project_startdate;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe.  I thought you wanted a temporary variable.  A private field is not temporary, unless the object it is part of is also temporary.  Your question is unclear ...

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to even write a temporary variable. Can you provide an example? Thanks

Comment: Before I do that, you need to explain clearly what you mean by temporary.  What is the timescale for "temporary"?  Is the variable used in a single method call?  In other words, are you just talking about a local variable?

Comment: Yes I am talking about a local variable. I tried this approach but nothing

```Date date_initial = new Date(project_startdate);```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing"?  Perhaps you should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see what the problem is.  Or at least source code that includes everything that the method depends on; i.e. relevant field declarations, code that initializes the fields, etc.

Comment: Nothing as it can display the date but the date changes as well. Another Java developer said that I am defining the same method and I need to create a separate one where it updates that date and one where it keeps the old. Is there an approach to that?

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.  I am waiting for you to post a minimal reproducible example that 1) shows the context and 2) illustrates what you are saying it happening.  (I presume the "other developer" can see more of your codebase than ... this.  And they can actually talk to you.   Perhaps you should just take their advice?)

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think I found a temporary value holder but I did define the initial date as another variable inside the initializer. By placing it here, I save the date before it is changed and updated via hibernate.

```
public Station() {
        super();
        Date date_initial = this.project_startdate;
    }
```

At the top of the class called Station. From there I also defined the getter and setter for date initial.

```
public Date getDate_initial(){
        return date_initial;
    }

    public void setDate_initial(Date date_initial) {
        this.date_initial = date_initial;
    }
```

From there it accurately compares the initial date to the updated date. If it is safe then it continues to save. Otherwise it displays an error message to the user.